# Class does not exist symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having a problem recovering my entities, the entities are in the AppBundle / Entity folder, but symfony can not find it ...

Here is the error: ***Class 'Product' does not exist***

Here is the function myManager () present in a controller

```
public function myManager(){
$isDevMode = true;
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/AppBundle/Entity"), $isDevMode);

// database configuration parameters
        $conn = array(
            'dbname' => 'teste',
            'user' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        );

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
return $entityManager;
}
```

the function testAction () that calls the manager and tries to load the Product entity

```
public function testAction(){
    $em = $this->myManager()->getRepository('Product');
    return $this->render('toto.html.twig');
}
```

link of documentation : [Doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html)

Comment: I'm guessing that you are not using the actual Symfony frame work so use the full qualified class name:  $repo->get('AppBundle\Entity\Product')

Comment: Why don't use use the DoctrineBundle by the way? I don't see a use case for a custom EntityManager here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the correct notation to make a reference to your entity:

```
$manager->getRepository('MyBundleName:Product')
```